# migrating From Prototype to jQuery what will be equivalent of new Ajax.updater

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, prototype

The below code  need to migrate  from prototype to jQuery i have written the equivalent of this code but have doubt in how to handle **{success: 'added_udf_filters'}** in jQuery

```
 new Ajax.Updater({success: 'added_udf_filters'}, '/reports/add_udf_selection_row', {
       parameters: {udf_key: filter_key},
       method: 'get',
       insertion: 'bottom',
       evalScripts:  true,
        onCreate: function() {
        $('udfFiltersWorking').show();
       },
       onComplete: function() {
         $('udfFiltersWorking').hide();
       },
       onSuccess: function(response) {
         sel_obj.select('[value=' + filter_key + ']')[0].remove();
         if ($('select_udf_filter').select('option').length <= 1)
           $('filter_select').up('table').hide();
       },
       onFailure: function(response) {
         alert("Error: " + response.statusText);
       }
     });
  }
 });
```

The Equivalent code which i have written in jQuery is

```
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/reports/add_udf_selection_row',
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(data) {
        jQuery("#added_udf_filters").html(data);
      }
    })
      .done(function(data) { 
        sel_obj.select('[value=' + filter_key + ']')[0].remove();
        if (jQuery('#select_udf_filter').select('option').length <= 1)
          jQuery('#filter_select').closest('table').hide();
      })

      .always(function() { jQuery('#udfFiltersWorking').hide(); })

      .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
        "use strict";
        alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ' : ' + ex);
      });
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @RomainFournereau  My Question is how to handle {success: 'added_udf_filters'}  in jQuery which is written in new Ajax.Updater?